# Accessing stringified JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

As another user in my other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360935/accessing-json-data-from-a-url/18361396?noredirect=1#comment26961310_18361396) suggested to post another question here in regards to explaining how to access JSON Objects. The code I am using is:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $.getJSON(
       "https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/wvw/matches.json",
        function (data) {
            $("#reply").html(JSON.stringify(data));
            // or work with the data here, already in object format
        });
});
</script>
```

What I am trying to do with [the JSON code](https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/wvw/matches.json), is to search through for a specified `world_id` and return the `match_id`. I'm very new to JavaScript so I'm not too sure how to do it, and how to access the stringified data which the code above gives me.

The way I figured how to do this, is to create an array and store each object in it, then loop through and check for a matching id like,

```
if(obj[i].red_world_id == 'xxxx' || obj[i].blue_world_id == 'xxxx' || obj[i].green_world_id == 'xxxx') {
    return obj[i].wvw_match_id;
}
```

My only problem is I'm not sure how to set an array as the JSON data.

Comment: You should append the JSON.

Comment: this json is already an array

Comment: You already had an object before you turned it into a string, and you could just iterate and search for keys and values in that directly, so why turn it into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.use this code -

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/wvw/matches.json", function(
            data) {
        $("#reply").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        // or work with the data here, already in object format
        var result = [];//for if it has many matches
        for ( var i=0;i<data.wvw_matches.length;i++ ) {
            var obj = data.wvw_matches[i];
            if (obj.red_world_id == 'xxxx' || obj.blue_world_id == 'xxxx'
                    || obj.green_world_id == 'xxxx') {
                result.push(obj.wvw_match_id);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `for...in` to loop over an array. Also, it should be `data.wvw_matches` rather than just `data`. You should use `for (var i = 0; i < data.wvw_matches.length; i++) { var obj = data.wvw_matches[i];` instead of `for...in`

Comment: returning a value from an asynchronous request will do absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to stringify, you could work with the JSON object directly:

```
function(data) {
    var filteredArray=$.grep(data.wvw_matches, function (item) {
        return (item.red_world_id == 'xxxx' || item.blue_world_id == 'xxxx' || item.green_world_id == 'xxxx');
    });
}
```

[See this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) for information on jQuery.grep.